# Nextjs Update List page after creating new record

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I am creating a Nextjs V 13.4 app in which I have created a Role page where users can create roles and then see the role list after creating. So I have two routes using **App Router**

**roles/create**

**roles/manage**

when I go to **role/create** page I have a form. After submitting that form I re-route the user to **roles/manage** page using

```
router.push("/admin/role/manage")
```

where the new data is supposed to be loaded. But It isn't.

**Role Form  Component**

```
 const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    if (isEmpty(data.id)) {
      let url = "/api/role/create";
      await axios.post(url, data);
    } else {
      let url = `/api/role/${data.id}`;
      await axios.put(url, data);
    }
    router.push("/admin/role/manage");
  };
```

**Manage Role Page:**

```
const ManageRolesPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
              <Suspense fallback={<ManageRoleListLoading />}>
                <ManageRoles />
              </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default ManageRolesPage;

**ManageRoles: Server Component used in suspense**

```
const ManageRoles = async () => {
  const roles = await fetchData("/role/list");
  return (
    <>
      <ManageRoleList roles={roles} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ManageRoles;
```

**Finally ManageRoleList: Client Component:**

```
type ManageRoleListProps = {
  roles: RoleListModel[];
};
const ManageRoleList = ({ roles }: ManageRoleListProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [selectedRoles, setSelectedRoles] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
     
      <div className="table-responsive mt-4">
        <DataTable
          tableClassName="table table-rounded"
          value={roles}
          dataKey="id"
          selectionMode="checkbox"
          selection={selectedRoles}>
         
          <Column header="Role Name" field="name"></Column>

        </DataTable>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ManageRoleList;
```

> **How to update the Mnage role page after creating new role?**